# Will a Star Fragment disappear if I use fast travel?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I saw a Star Fragment land a fair distance away from me while exploring at night. I was going to run towards it, when I noticed it had landed right next to a tower I could fast travel to.

If I fast travel to a tower near where a Star Fragment landed, will the Fragment disappear?

Comment: No, unless you've gotten close enough to the fragment that the column of light disappears and the fragment spawns in.

Comment: It will despawn if the ingame time passes a certain point (I think 5 a.m.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, no.

According to [Videogamer](https://www.videogamer.com/guides/tears-of-the-kingdom-how-to-catch-falling-star/):

> When you spot one, open up your map in the Purah Pad, and fast travel to the Skyview Tower closest to the falling star's location.